# Have a discord bot Disconnect from a call if the amount of members is less than 2

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to have my discord bot disconnect from a call when it's the only thing in the call and I have that bit of code as

```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(after, before, member):
   if member.voice < 2:
    await voice.disconnect()
   else :
       print("False")
```

what do I have wrong here?

Comment: You have not defined `voice`

Comment: On a side note, I recommend being consistent with indentation. Your code looks neater, there won't be any chance of an IndentationError... it's a win-win situation.

Answer (score 0):

When your bot connects to the call, set a variable to the `connect` function. For example, if your voice channel was stored in `channel`, and you did `await channel.connect()`, you would change that to `voice=await channel.connect()`. That's all!